# Add a choicefield to search_fields in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Say, I have a model with a choice field that looks like this:

```
STARTED = 1
DONE = 0

STATUSES = {
    (STARTED, 'Started'),
    (DONE, 'Done'),
}

status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES)
```

I'd like to add the field `status` to `search_fields = ()` in `admin.py` like below.

```
search_fields = (status,)
```

It works searching by integer but I'd like to search based on the display text "Done" and "Started."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by overriding the [`get_search_results`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) method of your model admin.

```
# This dictionary lets you convert the text back to the integer.
# You might prefer to build it dynamically instead.

TEXT_TO_STATUS_INTEGER = {
    'Started': 1,
    'DONE': 0,
}

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        if search_term in TEXT_TO_STATUS_INTEGER:
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(status=TEXT_TO_STATUS_INTEGER[search_term])
    return queryset, use_distinct
```

Comment: I was getting `KeyError` but was able to debug your code. `search_term` is the integer retrieved and should be passed to the filter directly like this `queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(status=search_term)`