# Doing text lookup for a ModelChoiceField on Admin gets an error

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I've a model that has a text field
I added a form with Django-Autocomplete to get the available objects for this field.

In the admin page for this model, i'd like to search for objects, using the my_field field but i get an error "Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"

I understand that i get it because the form's field is now ModelChoiceField, how can i fix it to search based on the SomeOtherModel's name field?

```
from dal import autocomplete
import django.forms as forms
from django.db import models

# models.py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
     some_other_model = models.ForeignKey('SomeOtherModel', )

class SomeOtherModel(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

#admin.py
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = SomeModelForm
     search_fields = ['some_other_model__name', ]

#form.py
class SomeModelForm(ModelForm):
    some_other_model = forms.ModelChoiceField(
         queryset=SomeOtherModel.objects.all(),
         widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='control:someothermodel-autocomplete', )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change the search_fields using a custom get_search_results and also use the other fields/list results

```
#admin.py
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeModelForm
    search_fields = []
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        new_queryset, use_distinct = super(SomeModelAdmin, self).\
        get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        new_queryset |= 
            queryset.filter(SomeOtherModel__name__icontains=search_term)
        return new_queryset, use_distinct
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765500/add-a-choicefield-to-search-fields-in-django-admin)